# Php string cast vs strval function which should I use?

Tags: php, string

What is the difference between doing a string cast and `strval` in php ?

1. `strval($value)`;
2. `(string)$value`;

Comment: I was hoping that `strval($value)` would magically 'convert' a binary string into something that fits in the default (UTF-8) encoding of PHP. Then I realised all of the native string functions are actually byte functions. There is no advantage in using `strval()` over `(string)`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

> A value can be converted to a string using the (string) cast or the strval() function.

Looks the same to me.

Answer (score 11):

They are generally interchangeable because PHP uses automatic type conversion and a variable's type is determined by the context in which the variable is used.

Some differences are that `strval($var)` will return the string value of `$var` while `(string)$var` is explicitly converting the "type" of `$var` during evaluation.

Also, from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) for `strval()`:

> `$var` may be any scalar type or an object that implements the `__toString` method. You cannot use `strval()` on arrays or on objects that do not implement the `__toString` method.

As mentioned by @Lars `(string)` is generally faster.

Comment: "$var is actually changing the "type" of $var.": Thats wrong, because as long as you don't assign something to the variable nothing will change it. "You cannot use strval() on arrays or on objects that do not implement the __toString method." Thats right, but that also applies to the `(string)`-cast. Thus no different here.

Comment: I stand corrected. I have adjusted my answer to be more accurate.  The documentation on the boolean type page uses the phrase "explicitly convert" so I took that to mean that the type of $var was being changed but a call to settype() is required for that.

Comment: could you provide a link to the manual you are talking about?

Comment: The quote "To explicitly convert a value to boolean, use the (bool) or (boolean) casts." comes from the "Booleans" page... http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting just under the "Converting to boolean" section header.

Comment: "convert a value to boolean" is not the same as converting the expression, itself. The casting converts the type of the expression returned. To make this more clear, a constant, like `true` or `false` cannot be changed, at all. Nor can literals like `100`.

Comment: I would argue that casts are generally more preferred as canonical "modern" PHP. They may have small perf differences, but casting is also a technique used in numerous other languages. The trend in PHP has been moving from small C like functions to language features (destructuring, casting, null coalescing, etc) for common data operations. I think this follows a similar trend in other communities, too.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how this applies to various versions of PHP, but when looking at the generated opcodes, both variants *generate the same opcodes*, and thus perform exactly the same.

Input:

```
<?php
function s1(int $val) {
    return (string)$val;
}
function s2(int $val) {
    return strval($val);
}
```

Output as generated by https://3v4l.org/3gFWj/vld#output

```
Function s1:
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
1 jumps found. (Code = 62) Position 1 = -2
filename:       /in/3gFWj
function name:  s1
number of ops:  4
compiled vars:  !0 = $val
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  E >   RECV                                             !0      
   3     1        MAKE_REF                                         ~1      !0
         2      > RETURN                                                   ~1
   4     3*     > RETURN                                                   null

End of function s1

Function s2:
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
1 jumps found. (Code = 62) Position 1 = -2
filename:       /in/3gFWj
function name:  s2
number of ops:  4
compiled vars:  !0 = $val
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   5     0  E >   RECV                                             !0      
   6     1        MAKE_REF                                         ~1      !0
         2      > RETURN                                                   ~1
   7     3*     > RETURN                                                   null

End of function s2
```

Answer (score 6):

One is a function call, the other one is an internal typecast. Without having checked, I'd guess the latter one is faster by few cycles, but shouldn't really make a difference.

Comment: Some benchmark for this also containing concatenation and interpolation: http://leifw.wickland.net/2009/08/performance-of-converting-integer-to.html

Comment: This may have been correct in older version of PHP, I haven't verified that. But it's certainly not true anymore these days, because PHP now optimizes the function call away.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but according to PHPstorm `(string)` is faster

[image: (string) is faster]

Comment: Just to try to understand, because i don't find any sources of this, I did test it myself : `1000000` times of `strval` on `5.6.37` => `0.38586091995239` vs `(string)` => `0.30763101577759`. And on `7.2.8`, `strval` => `0.24432492256165` vs `(string)` => `0.24242401123047`. Tried with a random double `$double = 0.001614654;`. So good to know but not a big difference there (and wonder what was the value for the `up to 6x` result). Using `microtime(true)`.

Comment: For this warning to be displayed, you need the `PHP Inspections (EA Extended)` plugin. This is not displayed by default in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 2):

There is an advantage of using `strval()` over `(string)`, Which is we can use `strval` as a callback function, Something we cannot do with `(string)`.

```php
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
echo(json_encode($arr)); // [1,2,3]
$arr = array_map('strval', $arr);
echo(json_encode($arr)); // ["1","2","3"]
```

Comment: with "arrow" functions, you could simply do `$arr = array_map(fn($s) => (string)$s, $arr);`, classic anonymous function variant would be `function ($s) { return (string)$s; }`, all are pretty fast, in very very extreme cases strval can be a bit faster, probably due to direct translation to a native function call. But we're talking arrays with tens of thousands items and difference in miliseconds :-) So choose ***readability*** that suits you best.