# Create php array from strings that contains bracket literals

Tags: php

I have a number of strings, that contain the bracket literals:

```
0 => string '[139432,97]' (length=18)
1 => string '[139440,99]' (length=18)
```

I need to create string arrays of `[139432,97]` and `[139440,99]`.

I've tried using `json_decode()`, but while it works, it creates arrays as `float` or `int` using the above data, however I want them as `strings`.

```
array (size=2)
0 => float 139432
1 => int 97

array (size=2)
0 => float 139440
1 => int 97
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put double quotes around the values e.g.

```
0 => string '["139432","97"]' (length=22)
1 => string '["139440","99"]' (length=22)
```

This way when you `json_decode` they should be strings.

**Edit:**

OK I thought you could control the input - if not then a simple trim and explode could do:

```
explode(',', trim('[139432,97]', '[]'));

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "139432"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "97"
}
```

Is that enough?

Comment: I would have to programatically add those quotes around the values because the data is coming from external source as is

Comment: OK I modified the answer above

Answer (score 1):

Just combining what you already now *(json_decode)* and what @AlixAxel suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2131489/4960774) you can extract those values to string link:

```js
$subject = '[139432,97]';
$convertedToArrayOfStrings = array_map('strval', json_decode($subject));
```

or

```
$convertedToArrayOfString = array_map(function($item){return (string) $item;}, json_decode($subject));
```

for better performance, see the comment bellow please :)

Comment: And if you are concern about performance, based on what i just learned from @KimHogeling's comment on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371991/php-string-cast-vs-strval-function-which-should-i-use) and [this](http://leifw.wickland.net/2009/08/performance-of-converting-integer-to.html) you can replace the **strval** with an anonymous method and cast your values e.g. `$convertedToArrayOfString = array_map(function($item){return (string) $item;}, json_decode($subject));`

Answer (score 0):

Why not try with loop and use explode function:

```
$array = array('139432,97', '139440,99');
$finalArray = array();

$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $explode = explode(",", $arr);
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($explode as $exp) {
       $finalArray[$i][$j] = (int)$exp;
       $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I had tried explode, but because the data is coming externally, the brackets are included, so I would need to massage it further, to use what you have on first line