# Getting values to compare from a Explode Array of Strings

Tags: php

I have this string that I'm Getting from a Mysql Result:

***Result1:***

```
1/test3&2/test4&
```

Then, I have some ID from another mysql Result like this:

***Result2:***

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

Then I'm using an Explode in order to separate ***Result1:***. Like I'm Getting this:

```
$nota3 = explode("&", $nota);

1/test3&
2/test4&
```

Now, I'm doing I'm using a foreach and then using another explode to separate the string by "/" delimiter.

```
foreach ($nota3 as $key) {

$nota4 = explode("/", $key);

}
```

The Result of this its something like this (for the firsts foreach iteration):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "test3"
}
```

Ok, So I cannot Compare `nota4[0]` with `$id` from ***Result2:***

Things that I've Tried:

- Using if and verify every type, converts `nota4[0]` a `$id` to string
- Try to use in_Array
- Try to use strcmp($var1, $var2)

I'm Missing something but I really dont know what.

Also, when I tried I cant put `nota4[0]` into a html String like

```
$nota5= nota4[0];

echo "<p id='mic' class='text-dark bg-warning'>".$nota5."</p>";
```

Maybe its something silly but I tried everything without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure both are strings and trim and use a strict operator - even if it seems they are already that

```
$result1 = "1/test3&2/test4&";
$result2 = "1";

$id = trim((string) $result2);
foreach ($nota3 as $key) {
  $nota4 = explode("/", $key);
  if (trim((string) $nota4[0]) === $id) {
     //...
  }
}
```

Here's another way to go about it. This will set up $result1 (or you can rename it) to become an associative array of key/value pairs, allowing you to loop through and compare a value like `$result2` with a key `id` in the `$result1` array. Example link included.

```
<?php

$result1 = "1/test3&2/test4&";
$result2 = "1";

$result1 = array_map(function ($a) { 
    $tmp =  explode("/", $a);
    return array('id' => $tmp[0],'name' => $tmp[1]);
}, array_filter(explode("&", $result1)));

print_r($result1);
```

now to get $result2

```
foreach ($result1 as $item) {
  if ($item['id'] == $result2) {
    // $value 
  }
}
```

Output of result1

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => test3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => test4
    )
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/1436vTBhUOYx9MNX

Comment: I need to compare result1 with result2

Comment: @JuanFernandoz I updated my answer again to specifically answer your question, and added an alternate way of parsing the data as well.

Comment: Sr, It worked like a charm,  In fact I tried your first solution but With srtval instead of String(). I'm Just a 35yr Lawyer from Colombia making something useful to my community here. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I would think either would work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371991/php-string-cast-vs-strval-function-which-should-i-use

Comment: Maybe Im missing something when used Srtval in my first try. Maybe the Trim or the Strict opperator.